# Moving from SQLte to Realm

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mobile, realm

I have a working app that uses SQLite as DB. I would like to move to Realm DB. Will this affect my existing users? How do I move over to Realm? My app is developed in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have created your schema, you need to iterate your sql values and add data in realm, for example(you need convert java to C#):

```
for (SqlTest sqlData : sqlTest) {
    Test test1 = realm.createObject(Test.class, UUID.randomUUID());
    test1.setName(sqlData.getName());
    test1.setSex(sqlData.getSex());
}
```